# Remove mixed-variable terms in SymPy series expansion

Tags: python, big-o, sympy, polynomial-approximations

Consider two functions of SymPy symbols `e` and `i`:

```
from sympy import Symbol, expand, Order
i = Symbol('i')
e = Symbol('e')
f = (i**3 + i**2 + i + 1)
g = (e**3 + e**2 + e + 1)
z = expand(f*g)
```

This will produce

```
z = e**3*i**3 + e**3*i**2 + e**3*i + e**3 + e**2*i**3 + e**2*i**2 + e**2*i + e**2 + e*i**3 + e*i**2 + e*i + e + i**3 + i**2 + i + 1
```

However, assume that `e` and `i` are both small and we can neglect both terms that are order three or higher. Using Sympy’s series tool or simply adding an O-notation `Order` class can handle this:

```
In : z = expand(f*g + Order(i**3) + Order(e**3))
Out: 1 + i + i**2 + e + e*i + e*i**2 + e**2 + e**2*i + e**2*i**2 + O(i**3) + O(e**3)
```

Looks great. However, I am still left with mixed terms `e**2 * i**2`. Individual variables in these terms are less than the desired cut-off so SymPy keeps them. However, mathematically small²·small² = small⁴. Likewise, e·i² = small·small² = small³.

At least for my purposes, I want these mixed terms dropped. Adding a mixed `Order` does not produce the desired result (it seems to ignore the first two orders).

```
In : expand(f*g + Order(i**3) + Order(e**3) + Order((i**2)*(e**2)))
Out: 1 + i + i**2 + i**3 + e + e*i + e*i**2 + e*i**3 + e**2 + e**2*i + e**3 + e**3*i + O(e**2*i**2, e, i)
```

**Question:** Does SymPy have an easy system to quickly remove the n-th order terms, as well as terms that are (e^a)·(i^b) where a+b > n?

**Messy Solution:** I have found a way to solve this, but it is messy and potentially not general.

```
z = expand(f*g + Order((e**2)*i) + Order(e*(i**2)))
zz = expand(z.removeO() + Order(e**3) + Order(i**3))
```

produces

```
zz = 1 + i + i**2 + e + e*i + e**2 + O(i**3) + O(e**3)
```

which is exactly what I want. So to specify my question: **Is there a way to do this in one step that can be generalized to any n?** Also, my solution loses the big-O notation that indicates mixed-terms were lost. This is not needed but would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a dual limit, you must specify both infinitesimal variables (`e` and `i`) in all `Order` objects, even if they don’t appear in the first argument.

The reason for this is that `Order(expr)` only automatically chooses those symbols as infinitesimal that actually appear in the `expr` and thus, e.g., `O(e)` is only for the limit e→0.
Now, `Order` objects with different limits don’t mix well, e.g.:

```
O(e*i)+O(e) == O(e*i) != O(e)+O(e*i) == O(e) # True
```

This leads to a mess where results depend on the order of addition, which is a good indicator that this is something to avoid.
This can be avoided by explicitly specifying the infinitesimal symbols (as addition arguments of `Order`), e.g.:

```
O(e*i)+O(e,e,i) == O(e,e,i)+O(e*i) == O(e,e,i) # True
```

I haven’t found a way to avoid going through all combinations of `e` and `i` manually, but this can be done by a simple iteration:

```
orders = sum( Order(e**a*i**(n-a),e,i) for a in range(n+1) )
expand(f*g+orders)
# 1 + i + i**2 + e + e*i + e**2 + O(e**2*i, e, i) + O(e*i**2, e, i) + O(i**3, e, i) + O(e**3, e, i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using Order you might try something simple like this:

```
>>> eq = expand(f*g)  # as you defined
>>> def total_degree(e):
...     x = Dummy()
...     free = e.free_symbols
...     if not free: return S.Zero
...     for f in free:
...         e = e.subs(f, x)
...     return degree(e)
>>> eq.replace(lambda x: total_degree(x) > 2, lambda x: S.Zero)
e**2 + e*i + e + i**2 + i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way about it using Poly. I have made a function that keeps the O(...) term and another that does not (faster).

```
from sympy import Symbol, expand, Order, Poly
i = Symbol('i')
e = Symbol('e')
f = (i**3 + i**2 + i + 1)
g = (e**3 + e**2 + e + 1)
z = expand(f*g)

def neglect(expr, order=3):
    z = Poly(expr)
    
    # extract all terms and keep the lower order ones
    d = z.as_dict()
    d = {t: c for t,c in d.items() if sum(t) < order}
    
    # Build resulting polynomial
    return Poly(d, z.gens).as_expr()
        
def neglectO(expr, order=3):
    # This one keeps O terms
    z = Poly(expr)
    
    # extract terms of higher "order"
    d = z.as_dict()
    large = {t: c for t,c in d.items() if sum(t) >= order}
    for t in large:  # Add each O(large monomial) to the expression
        expr += Order(Poly({t:1},z.gens).as_expr(), *z.gens)
    
    return expr

print(neglect(z))
print(neglectO(z))
```

This code prints the following:

```
e**2 + e*i + e + i**2 + i + 1
1 + i + i**2 + e + e*i + e**2 + O(e**2*i, e, i) + O(e*i**2, e, i) + O(i**3, e, i) + O(e**3, e, i)
```